# Number of operations to compute product of pairwise sums over a commutative semiring

Tags: ds.algorithms, algebra

Let $S$ be a commutative semiring and $T\subset S$, how many semiring operations are required to compute the following
$$\prod_{a,b\in T} a+b$$?

This problem can be solved for commutative rings in $O(n \log n)$ ring operations using multipoint polynomial evaluation from [a related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304687/can-product-of-all-pairwise-sums-be-computed-faster-than-the-naive-method). However, the algorithm requires there is an inverse to addition.

Actually I'm mostly interested in a similar problem. We have $M = \{A_1,\ldots,A_k\}$ such that $A_i\subset S$. We want to compute

$$\prod_{A\in M} \prod_{A\neq B\in M} \prod_{a\in A,b\in B} a+b$$

with least number of semiring operations.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to your exact question, but may be useful if you happen to have a semiring with cancellation: if you have an algorithm which works in any ring, you can apply that algorithm to the difference ring $S-S$ consisting of subtraction pairs $s - t$.  The result will have the form $s - t$ where $s,t \in S$, and the answer will be $d \in S$ s.t. $s = d + t$.  Thus, in addition to semiring operations, you'd need to perform a single cancellation step at the end.

Comment: A difference ring can be defined only for a semiring with the cancellation property with respect to addition (x+z=y+z ⇒ x=y).  For example, the (min, +) semiring on ℕ∪{∞} does not have the cancellation property.  Therefore, I do not think that this trick works.